# PHP, odbc mdb insert max id +1

Tags: php, ms-access, odbc

I am trying to make a code to insert a new row into an access .mdb with php, But I can't get it to work so far i have done this to insert

```
$ins = ("INSERT INTO Klanten (KLANTNR, VOORNAAM, ACHTERNAAM, ADRES, POSTCODE, WOONPLAATS, PROVINCIE, TELEFOON) VALUES ((SELECT max(KLANTNR) FROM Klanten)+1,'$voornaam', '$achternaam', '$adres', '$postcode', '$woonplaats', '$provisie', '$telefoon');");
```

but

```
(SELECT max(KLANTNR) FROM Klanten)+1
```

won't work.

Does any one have an idea, how to fix this

BTW. the rest of my code is working fine

sorry for my bad English i'm learning it.

Kind regards, 
Tom

Comment: Enterox, can you confirm that your SQL code executes correctly in your database? Can you also use a `var $aVarForSQL = (SELECT max(KLANTNR) FROM Klanten)`, execute that and then `var_dump($aVarForSQL )`, and add that to your question.... finally, please, read
[this (how to ask)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and
[this (mcve)](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) before asking,
as those will help you get more and better answers from the community.

Comment: just tried but din't work

Comment: I'd use separate query for `max + 1`.

Comment: Yes, but for us, we dont have enough information to help you... you have to keep on editting your question, and posting the relevant code, so that we may understand the problem, and guide you through it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do `select` from same table and without using `values`:

```
INSERT INTO Klanten (
    KLANTNR,
    VOORNAAM,
    ACHTERNAAM,
    ADRES,
    POSTCODE,
    WOONPLAATS,
    PROVINCIE,
    TELEFOON
) SELECT
    MAX(KLANTNR) + 1,
    '$voornaam',
    '$achternaam',
    '$adres',
    '$postcode',
    '$woonplaats',
    '$provisie',
    '$telefoon'
FROM
    Klanten
```

Answer (score 0):

`SELECT max(KLANTNR)+1 FROM Klanten`